# Docker and makefile how to fix

Tags: docker, go, makefile

I have go web application and im trying to deploy on Docker but im keep getting this messages. Im Running this on Windows 10 enterprise 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz   64 bit
Docker file

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app
COPY bin/main /app/main
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

MAKEFILE

```
GOOS=linux
GOARCH=amd64
build:
    go build -o bin/main main.go
run:
    go run main.go
compile:
    echo "Compiling for every OS and Platform"
    GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build -o bin/main-linux-arm main.go
    GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -o bin/main-linux-arm64 main.go
    GOOS=freebsd GOARCH=386 go build -o bin/main-freebsd-386 main.go
```

im running this commands

```
go build -o bin/main main.go
docker build -t tiny .
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 tiny
```

error im getting: **exec /app/main: exec format error**

go file: **log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe (":8080",nil))**

Comment: You're using the `main` binary built on your host system, which is the wrong OS (Windows host but Linux container).  Do you need to `RUN go build ...` in the Dockerfile?

Comment: So how do i fix that im new to deocker

Answer (score 0):

When your Dockerfile says

```bash
COPY bin/main /app/main
```

you're copying a `main` binary built on your (Windows) host system into your (Linux) Docker image.  Since the operating systems don't match, you're getting that "exec format error" message.

It's very common when you're building a Docker image to do the actual compilation step in the Dockerfile itself.  In a compiled language like Go, a further extremely common approach is to use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) so that the Go toolchain itself isn't part of the final image; this gives you a much smaller image and doesn't republish your source code to end users.

```bash
FROM golang:1.19-bullseye AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN go build -o main ./

FROM debian:bullseye
COPY --from=build /app/main /usr/local/bin/main
CMD ["main"]
```

This approach ignores your Makefile, which isn't really using any Make features (for example, there is nowhere one rule depends on another, and there is nowhere you might skip a rule execution if its output file already exists).  This particular Dockerfile builds a dynamically-linked binary, and makes sure the build and execution phase are using the same major version of the same Linux distribution, and therefore the same system C library.

Comment: Thank you it worked but i got another problem docker is running but when i go to port on browser it gives me this error: This page isn’t working127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Is it because of windows ?

Comment: That could happen if your application isn't listening on `0.0.0.0:8080` (if it's listening on `127.0.0.1` it will not be reachable from outside its own container), or potentially there's a bad interaction with `-p 127.0.0.1:...` and Windows.  But that'd be a separate question.